# Android The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

```
public class ListSceneAdapter extends OAListSceneAdapter {

    public ListSceneAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.listitem); // pass the custom UI layout for list items
    }

    @Override
    protected void setupListItemView(View listItemView, OAScene scene) {
        // fill the custom UI with the given scene data for the list item
        ((TextView)listItemView.findViewById(R.id.listItemName)).setText(scene.name);

        // add listener for the button
        final OAScene _scene = scene;
        ((Button)listItemView.findViewById(R.id.listItemButton)).setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), _scene.description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

        ((Button)listItemView.findViewById(R.id.listItemMap)).setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        double lat = 1.559034;
                        double longi =103.641486;

                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                                Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="+ lat + "," + longi+ "&daddr="+_scene.getLatitude()+","+_scene.getLongitude()+""));
                        intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
                        startActivity(intent);

                        //Toast.makeText(getContext(), _scene.description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
    }



}
```

heres the code. when i try to onClick and open new activity which give navigation from Google Map api.. it giver this error..
The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}

heres the LOGCAT

```
12-21 11:30:10.867: D/SensorManager(4782): ====>>>>>Num Sensor: 1
12-21 11:30:10.867: D/SensorManager(4782): ====>>>>>Num Sensor: 2
12-21 11:30:10.875: D/SensorManager(4782): ====>>>>>Num Sensor: 3
12-21 11:30:10.875: D/SensorManager(4782): ====>>>>>Num Sensor: 4
12-21 11:30:10.875: D/SensorManager(4782): ====>>>>>Num Sensor: 5
12-21 11:30:10.875: D/SensorManager(4782): ====>>>>>Num Sensor: 6
12-21 11:30:10.875: D/SensorManager(4782): ====>>>>>Num Sensor: 0
12-21 11:30:10.898: I/inertialManager(4782): Rotation is: 0 or 180
12-21 11:30:10.898: I/intertialManager(4782): Natural Orientation is landscape
12-21 11:30:11.000: W/System.err(4782): java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse 'main' as integer
12-21 11:30:11.015: W/System.err(4782):     at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:383)
12-21 11:30:11.015: W/System.err(4782):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:372)
12-21 11:30:11.015: W/System.err(4782):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
12-21 11:30:11.015: W/System.err(4782):     at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:506)
12-21 11:30:11.015: W/System.err(4782):     at com.hitlabnz.androidar.utils.SceneXMLReader.characters(SceneXMLReader.java:427)
12-21 11:30:11.015: W/System.err(4782):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.text(ExpatParser.java:165)
12-21 11:30:11.015: W/System.err(4782):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.appendBytes(Native Method)
12-21 11:30:11.015: W/System.err(4782):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseFragment(ExpatParser.java:518)
12-21 11:30:11.015: W/System.err(4782):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseDocument(ExpatParser.java:479)
12-21 11:30:11.015: W/System.err(4782):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:318)
12-21 11:30:11.015: W/System.err(4782):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:275)
12-21 11:30:11.015: W/System.err(4782):     at com.hitlabnz.androidar.utils.SceneXMLReader.readManifest(SceneXMLReader.java:549)
12-21 11:30:11.015: W/System.err(4782):     at com.hitlabnz.androidar.data.management.DataLoaderLocalXML.getSceneData(DataLoaderLocalXML.java:72)
12-21 11:30:11.015: W/System.err(4782):     at com.hitlabnz.androidar.data.management.DataLoaderLocalXML.getSceneData(DataLoaderLocalXML.java:1)
12-21 11:30:11.015: W/System.err(4782):     at com.hitlabnz.outdoorar.data.OADataManagerAssets.loadScenes(OADataManagerAssets.java:200)
12-21 11:30:11.015: W/System.err(4782):     at com.hitlabnz.outdoorar.data.OADataManager.startLoading(OADataManager.java:266)
12-21 11:30:11.015: W/System.err(4782):     at com.hitlabnz.outdoorar.api.OAListComponentBase.setupScenes(OAListComponentBase.java:87)
12-21 11:30:11.015: W/System.err(4782):     at com.hitlabnz.outdoorar.api.OAListComponentBase.onCreate(OAListComponentBase.java:167)
12-21 11:30:11.015: W/System.err(4782):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-21 11:30:11.015: W/System.err(4782):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
12-21 11:30:11.015: W/System.err(4782):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
12-21 11:30:11.015: W/System.err(4782):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
12-21 11:30:11.023: W/System.err(4782):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
12-21 11:30:11.023: W/System.err(4782):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-21 11:30:11.023: W/System.err(4782):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-21 11:30:11.023: W/System.err(4782):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
12-21 11:30:11.023: W/System.err(4782):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-21 11:30:11.023: W/System.err(4782):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-21 11:30:11.023: W/System.err(4782):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
12-21 11:30:11.023: W/System.err(4782):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
12-21 11:30:11.023: W/System.err(4782):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-21 11:30:11.054: W/System.err(4782): java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse 'main' as integer
12-21 11:30:11.062: W/System.err(4782):     at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:383)
12-21 11:30:11.062: W/System.err(4782):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:372)
12-21 11:30:11.062: W/System.err(4782):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
12-21 11:30:11.070: W/System.err(4782):     at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:506)
12-21 11:30:11.070: W/System.err(4782):     at com.hitlabnz.androidar.utils.SceneXMLReader.characters(SceneXMLReader.java:427)
12-21 11:30:11.070: W/System.err(4782):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.text(ExpatParser.java:165)
12-21 11:30:11.070: W/System.err(4782):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.appendBytes(Native Method)
12-21 11:30:11.070: W/System.err(4782):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseFragment(ExpatParser.java:518)
12-21 11:30:11.070: W/System.err(4782):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseDocument(ExpatParser.java:479)
12-21 11:30:11.070: W/System.err(4782):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:318)
12-21 11:30:11.070: W/System.err(4782):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:275)
12-21 11:30:11.070: W/System.err(4782):     at com.hitlabnz.androidar.utils.SceneXMLReader.readManifest(SceneXMLReader.java:549)
12-21 11:30:11.070: W/System.err(4782):     at com.hitlabnz.androidar.data.management.DataLoaderLocalXML.getSceneData(DataLoaderLocalXML.java:72)
12-21 11:30:11.070: W/System.err(4782):     at com.hitlabnz.androidar.data.management.DataLoaderLocalXML.getSceneData(DataLoaderLocalXML.java:1)
12-21 11:30:11.070: W/System.err(4782):     at com.hitlabnz.outdoorar.data.OADataManagerAssets.loadScenes(OADataManagerAssets.java:200)
12-21 11:30:11.070: W/System.err(4782):     at com.hitlabnz.outdoorar.data.OADataManager.startLoading(OADataManager.java:266)
12-21 11:30:11.070: W/System.err(4782):     at com.hitlabnz.outdoorar.api.OAListComponentBase.setupScenes(OAListComponentBase.java:87)
12-21 11:30:11.070: W/System.err(4782):     at com.hitlabnz.outdoorar.api.OAListComponentBase.onCreate(OAListComponentBase.java:167)
12-21 11:30:11.070: W/System.err(4782):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-21 11:30:11.070: W/System.err(4782):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
12-21 11:30:11.070: W/System.err(4782):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
12-21 11:30:11.070: W/System.err(4782):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
12-21 11:30:11.070: W/System.err(4782):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
12-21 11:30:11.070: W/System.err(4782):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-21 11:30:11.070: W/System.err(4782):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-21 11:30:11.070: W/System.err(4782):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
12-21 11:30:11.070: W/System.err(4782):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-21 11:30:11.070: W/System.err(4782):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-21 11:30:11.070: W/System.err(4782):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
12-21 11:30:11.070: W/System.err(4782):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
12-21 11:30:11.070: W/System.err(4782):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-21 11:30:11.242: W/System.err(4782): java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse 'main' as integer
12-21 11:30:11.242: W/System.err(4782):     at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:383)
12-21 11:30:11.242: W/System.err(4782):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:372)
12-21 11:30:11.242: W/System.err(4782):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
12-21 11:30:11.242: W/System.err(4782):     at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:506)
12-21 11:30:11.242: W/System.err(4782):     at com.hitlabnz.androidar.utils.SceneXMLReader.characters(SceneXMLReader.java:427)
12-21 11:30:11.242: W/System.err(4782):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.text(ExpatParser.java:165)
12-21 11:30:11.242: W/System.err(4782):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.appendBytes(Native Method)
12-21 11:30:11.242: W/System.err(4782):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseFragment(ExpatParser.java:518)
12-21 11:30:11.242: W/System.err(4782):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseDocument(ExpatParser.java:479)
12-21 11:30:11.242: W/System.err(4782):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:318)
12-21 11:30:11.242: W/System.err(4782):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:275)
12-21 11:30:11.242: W/System.err(4782):     at com.hitlabnz.androidar.utils.SceneXMLReader.readManifest(SceneXMLReader.java:549)
12-21 11:30:11.242: W/System.err(4782):     at com.hitlabnz.androidar.data.management.DataLoaderLocalXML.getSceneData(DataLoaderLocalXML.java:72)
12-21 11:30:11.242: W/System.err(4782):     at com.hitlabnz.androidar.data.management.DataLoaderLocalXML.getSceneData(DataLoaderLocalXML.java:1)
12-21 11:30:11.242: W/System.err(4782):     at com.hitlabnz.outdoorar.data.OADataManagerAssets.loadScenes(OADataManagerAssets.java:200)
12-21 11:30:11.250: W/System.err(4782):     at com.hitlabnz.outdoorar.data.OADataManager.startLoading(OADataManager.java:266)
12-21 11:30:11.250: W/System.err(4782):     at com.hitlabnz.outdoorar.api.OAListComponentBase.setupScenes(OAListComponentBase.java:87)
12-21 11:30:11.250: W/System.err(4782):     at com.hitlabnz.outdoorar.api.OAListComponentBase.onCreate(OAListComponentBase.java:167)
12-21 11:30:11.250: W/System.err(4782):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-21 11:30:11.250: W/System.err(4782):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
12-21 11:30:11.250: W/System.err(4782):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
12-21 11:30:11.250: W/System.err(4782):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
12-21 11:30:11.250: W/System.err(4782):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
12-21 11:30:11.250: W/System.err(4782):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-21 11:30:11.250: W/System.err(4782):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-21 11:30:11.250: W/System.err(4782):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
12-21 11:30:11.250: W/System.err(4782):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-21 11:30:11.250: W/System.err(4782):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-21 11:30:11.250: W/System.err(4782):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
12-21 11:30:11.250: W/System.err(4782):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
12-21 11:30:11.250: W/System.err(4782):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-21 11:30:11.398: D/dalvikvm(4782): GC_CONCURRENT freed 265K, 47% free 3001K/5639K, external 499K/517K, paused 3ms+10ms
12-21 11:30:11.398: I/GPSManager(4782): Network Location Provider available
12-21 11:30:11.468: E/SensorManager(4782): registerListener :: handle = 1600615030  name= Gravity Sensor delay= 20000 Listener= com.hitlabnz.androidar.sensors.inertial.InertialManager$3@4055af88
12-21 11:30:11.468: E/SensorManager(4782): =======>>>Sensor Thread RUNNING <<<========
12-21 11:30:11.476: E/SensorManager(4782): registerListener :: handle = 1  name= MMC328X delay= 20000 Listener= com.hitlabnz.androidar.sensors.inertial.InertialManager$2@4055ac88
12-21 11:30:11.476: E/SensorManager(4782): reg :: handle = 1
12-21 11:30:12.687: E/SensorManager(4782): unregisterListener:: all sensors,  listener = com.hitlabnz.androidar.sensors.inertial.InertialManager$2@4055ac88
12-21 11:30:12.695: E/SensorManager(4782): unregisterListener:: all sensors,  listener = com.hitlabnz.androidar.sensors.inertial.InertialManager$3@4055af88
12-21 11:30:12.804: I/GPSManager(4782): Network Location Provider available
12-21 11:30:12.867: E/SensorManager(4782): registerListener :: handle = 1600615030  name= Gravity Sensor delay= 20000 Listener= com.hitlabnz.androidar.sensors.inertial.InertialManager$3@4055af88
12-21 11:30:12.867: E/SensorManager(4782): registerListener :: handle = 1  name= MMC328X delay= 20000 Listener= com.hitlabnz.androidar.sensors.inertial.InertialManager$2@4055ac88
12-21 11:30:12.875: E/SensorManager(4782): reg :: handle = 1
12-21 11:30:12.976: D/AndroidRuntime(4782): Shutting down VM
12-21 11:30:12.976: W/dalvikvm(4782): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
12-21 11:30:13.039: E/AndroidRuntime(4782): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-21 11:30:13.039: E/AndroidRuntime(4782): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-21 11:30:13.039: E/AndroidRuntime(4782):     at com.hitlabnz.tutorialbasic.ListSceneAdapter$2.onClick(ListSceneAdapter.java:53)
12-21 11:30:13.039: E/AndroidRuntime(4782):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
12-21 11:30:13.039: E/AndroidRuntime(4782):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
12-21 11:30:13.039: E/AndroidRuntime(4782):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-21 11:30:13.039: E/AndroidRuntime(4782):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-21 11:30:13.039: E/AndroidRuntime(4782):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-21 11:30:13.039: E/AndroidRuntime(4782):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
12-21 11:30:13.039: E/AndroidRuntime(4782):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-21 11:30:13.039: E/AndroidRuntime(4782):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-21 11:30:13.039: E/AndroidRuntime(4782):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
12-21 11:30:13.039: E/AndroidRuntime(4782):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
12-21 11:30:13.039: E/AndroidRuntime(4782):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

OAListSceneAdapter class

```
/*
 * Copyright 2011 the Human Interface Technology Laboratory New Zealand, University of Canterbury.
 * http://www.hitlabnz.org
 * 
 * This software is provided under the license terms described in LICENSE.TXT file distributed with this software package.
 */

package com.hitlabnz.outdoorar.api;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.hitlabnz.androidar.data.SceneData;
import com.hitlabnz.outdoorar.R;

/**
 * Basic adapter class for making custom layout for list items in list components. 
 * @author Gun Lee
 */
public class OAListSceneAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SceneData> {

    protected LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private int listItemLayoutId;
    private Context c; 

    /**
     * Instantiate with the context to access the layout resource for list items.
     * Subclasses should override this method and call super(context, layoutResId) with a customized layout resource.
     * @param context   context for accessing resources
     */
    public OAListSceneAdapter(Context context) {
        this(context, R.layout.oa_list_item);
        c =context;
    }

    /**
     * Instantiate with the context to access the layout resource for list items.
     * Subclasses should NOT override this method.
     * @param context       context for accessing resources
     * @param layoutResId   resource id of the list item layout
     */
    protected OAListSceneAdapter(Context context, int layoutResId) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_item);

        this.layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        listItemLayoutId = layoutResId;
    }

    /**
     * Called back for setting up the list item view for a given scene.
     * Subclasses should override this method for setting up the list item view for the scene.
     * Subclasses need NOT to call the method in the super class.
     * @param listItemView  view for the list item, create with the layout resource id given at instan
     * @param scene
     */
    protected void setupListItemView(View listItemView, OAScene scene) {
        TextView nameText = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.listItemName);
        TextView categoryText = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.listItemCategory);

        nameText.setText(scene.name);
        if(scene.category == null)
            categoryText.setText("");
        else
            categoryText.setText("- " + scene.category);
    }

    /**
     * Called back for a view for the list item.
     * Subclasses should NOT override this method, but override the setupListItemView() method for customization.
     */
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(listItemLayoutId, parent, false);

        OAScene scene = (OAScene)this.getItem(position);
        setupListItemView(convertView, scene);
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the object activity class to the adapter, from which you are calling the adapter.  Then use that object to call startActivity.

Answer (score 13):

That's because `Listener`s don't start Activities.

I'm assuming that the Context passed to your class is available to the whole class via a getter method or something similar. If not, you can store a global reference to this `Context` when it is obtained via the constructor. You may need to make it final or the `Listener` *may* complain.

Anyways, what you have to do, is call

```
context.startActivity(intent)
```

instead of

```
startActivity(intent);
```

because [Contexts](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29) can start Activities.

Comment: hi @a--c i tried to do the following it give no error but it crash.......the activity is from google map api should i declare in activity? in Android manifest xml?

Comment: If it crashes, it has a LogCat, copy the whole red portion and edit your question to include that.

Comment: Ive copied the whole logCat :)

Comment: What is line 53 of `ListSceneAdapter`?

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and guess that you made a **global** `Context` variable and that is **null** when you try to access it from your `Listener`. Your constructor should have this line: `this.myGlobalVariable = context;` put it *after* the call to the superclass constructor.

Comment: i did this got error
public class ListSceneAdapter extends OAListSceneAdapter {
 Context con; 
 public ListSceneAdapter(Context context) {
  con = context;
  super(context, R.layout.listitem); // pass the custom UI layout for list items
  
 }

Comment: you call super *then* con = context;

Comment: still got error.. can you help me ? i will send my full source code. im editing AR framework call Mobile AR framework by hitlabnz....

Comment: i ll add here the extends OAListSceneAdapter Class ..wait.

Comment: i already edit the question above. please look into the code. thanks

Comment: You need to a)Update your code since ListSceneAdapter is outdated. b)tell us **where** it is crashing exactly (just because you posted the full source does not mean that the line numbers are the same) and c)What you have tried. Just dumping code here and going "figure it out" is not how you get people to help you.

Comment: thanks alot @A--C i know what happened. in adapter i didnt past the context value. now ive passed. and i can use c.startActivity :) ..thanks a lot for your help .. i m sorry if i put all codes here. im afraid people dont know that i use 2 java classes. and those are not mine. im still at learning stage.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ((Button)listItemView.findViewById(R.id.listItemMap)).setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                   Intent intent = new Intent(A.alias,B.class);

                        A.alias.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
```